# Unity Beta SDK 5.0.3 - Problems logging in on Android device

Tags: android, facebook-unity-sdk

I am having problems with logging in on my test android device.
I am calling:

```
FB.Login("", AfterLogin);
```

I get no error in the response but still the access token is empty
(i've noticed that on subsequent requests).

It is important to say that it works fine in the editor (by specifying the access token) and that i didn't test it on any other platform.

I have done everything according to the Facebook Unity SDK guide.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  We did find a bug with this and will be releasing a new version of the sdk shortly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I have struggled with this login problem for hours, 40 minutes after posting the question I have found out that this works as expected:

```
FB.Login("basic_info", AfterLogin);
```

Is it a bug in the SDK? Or maybe in the Facebook Android app?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bug.  It reads the empty string as a permission just like any other permission.  Since there is no permission that is an empty string, it'll fail.  We're getting it fixed like Ben said.  In the meantime your workaround is the correct solution.