# Unable to login / Facebook Unity SDK & Android

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-unity-sdk

Facebook Unity SDK: 5.0.3 beta

When I try to login having installed Facebook app it asks me if I'll allow this app to access my profile (then I can see on facebook in my profile applications page that access is given indeed), but nothing happens after this. Interactive console (example which comes with Unity SDK) still shows no signs that I've been logged.

Here is what happens in logcat when I press login button:

```
D/FBUnitySDK(21729): KeyHash: BR6n1yxjFrxzrkkeDey3fzy7Mb0=
V/FBUnitySDK(21729): sending to Unity OnLoginComplete({"cancelled":true,"key_hash":"BR6n1yxjFrxzrkkeDey3fzy7Mb0=\n"})
```

If I'll remove facebook app then it'll show me small webview, where I should enter my credentials. After entering it it'll simply reappering again with both input fields empty and there is no end to this reappearing (unless I give up and press Cancel/X).

Here is what happens in logcat when I trying to login in webview:

```
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1391609676100%7D&client_id=620142358054713&scope=email&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1391609676538%7D&client_id=620142358054713&scope=email&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Redirect URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=620142358054713&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D620142358054713%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1391609676538%257D&display=touch&_rdr
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=620142358054713&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D620142358054713%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1391609676538%257D&display=touch&_rdr
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=620142358054713&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D620142358054713%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1391609676538%257D&display=touch&_rdr
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D620142358054713%26ret%3Dlogin&refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&refid=9
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Redirect URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&scope=email&type=user_agent&client_id=620142358054713&ret=login&ext=1391613294&hash=Aea6t5pfgOeXQyOH&refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&refid=9&m_sess=c2VzczoxMDAwMDU2MzQ0ODY4ODI6Mjk6Uk5FLWFfTXV5RE9ZeHc6MjoxMzkxNjA5Njk0OjE0MDMx&_rdr#_=_
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess&display=touch&scope=email&type=user_agent&client_id=620142358054713&ret=login&ext=1391613294&hash=Aea6t5pfgOeXQyOH&refsrc=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Flogin.php&refid=9&m_sess=c2VzczoxMDAwMDU2MzQ0ODY4ODI6Mjk6Uk5FLWFfTXV5RE9ZeHc6MjoxMzkxNjA5Njk0OjE0MDMx&_rdr#_=_
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/confirm
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Redirect URL: fbconnect://success#access_token=xxx&expires_in=5179467
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?display=touch&e2e=%7B%22init%22%3A1391609698785%7D&client_id=620142358054713&scope=email&type=user_agent&redirect_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Redirect URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=620142358054713&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D620142358054713%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1391609698785%257D&display=touch&_rdr
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=620142358054713&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D620142358054713%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1391609698785%257D&display=touch&_rdr
D/FacebookSDK.WebDialog(21729): Webview loading URL: https://m.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=620142358054713&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fm.facebook.com%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dfbconnect%253A%252F%252Fsuccess%26display%3Dtouch%26scope%3Demail%26type%3Duser_agent%26client_id%3D620142358054713%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=fbconnect%3A%2F%2Fsuccess%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%26e2e%3D%257B%2522init%2522%253A1391609698785%257D&display=touch&_rdr
```

Login on IOS works just fine, but what's wrong I could be doing with android?

**UPDATE:** Everything works as should on 4.3.6 SDK version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login works only when I start logging in in portrait screen mode. If I start it in landscape - it forcefully changes to portrait and back but nothing happens aside from that. Tested a few times without rebuilding - confirmed. I believe this to be a bug.

Comment: In the meantime there's a fix you can do on your own:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21354281/facebook-unity-sdk-v5-0-3-crashes-in-landscape-mode-when-trying-to-login-andro/21368820#21368820

Answer (score 1):

Are you logging in without any permissions?  There's a known bug where `FB.Login()` doesn't work if no permissions is specified.  Try `FB.Login("basic_info", <your_callback>)`

see: [Unity Beta SDK 5.0.3 - Problems logging in on Android device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437235/unity-beta-sdk-5-0-3-problems-logging-in-on-android-device)

Comment: I'm logging with basic_info and email permissions specified

Answer (score 1):

There is a serious issue in the SDK.

The SDK uses phantom activity *FBUnityLoginActivity*, which calls *FB.LoginUsingActivity()* from *onCreate()* But the activity has no *android:configChanges* attribute, and it gets restarted by Android, because it switches from lansdcape to portrait. It results in a second call to *FB.LoginUsingActivity()*, which cancels previous asynchronous login.

The solution is to specify correct *android:configChanges* and *android:screenOrientation* on all activities.

I think Facebook team should use *runOnUiThread()* instead of phantom activity.